# When I try to package my python code into a .ZIP through YAML, the folder is empty

Tags: python, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-repos, azure-releases

I’m using Azure DevOps and I’m trying to package my python code into a .ZIP file. I’m also using Azure for my repo for my python folder.

[Here’s my folder in my repo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/heCCa.png)

[Here’s my YAML code for my pipeline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/klS9b.png)

Everything works fine, my only issue is that the .ZIP folder that gets published is completely empty and I want it to be my python file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, the source code files will be checked out to the directory "**`Build.SourcesDirectory`**" on the agent machine. The artifact files output from the build also are in this directory.

By default, the directory "**`Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory`**" is empty, the source code files and build artifact files will not be automatically added/generated into this directory.

Before archive a ZIP file from the directory "**`Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory`**", you should use the [**Copy Files task**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/copy-files?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) to copy the files which you want to archive from the directory "**`Build.SourcesDirectory`**" into the directory "**`Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory`**".

For more details, you can see view [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#build-variables-devops-services).

[image]

[image]